# Weird behavior parsing large text file using a foreach loop (C# .NET 4)

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

i have a VERY large text file to parse (~2GB). for various reasons i have to process the file line-wise. i do this by loading the text file to memory (the server I'm running the parser on has way enough memory) with `var records = Regex.Split(File.ReadAllText(dumpPath, Encoding.Default), @"my regex here").Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s));`. this consumes RAM  equivalent to the size of the text file plus a few MBs for the `IEnumerable` overhead. so far so good.
then i go over the collection with `foreach (var recordsd in records) {...}`

here comes the interesting part. i do a lot of string manipulation and regex-ing in the foreach loop. then the program quickly bombs with an System.OutOfMemoryException, even though i never use more than a few kB in the foreach loop.
i made a few memory snapshots using the profiler of my choice (ANTS memory profiler), seeing millions and millions of Generation 2 string objects on the heap, consuming all available memory.

seeing that, i - **just as a test** - included a `GC.Collect();` at the end of each foreach iteration, and voila, problem solved and no more out of memory exceptions (sure enough because of the permanent garbage collections the program now runs painstakingly slow). The only memory consumed is the size of the actual file.

now i can't explain why this happens and how to prevent it. to my understanding, the very moment a variable goes out of scope and has no more (active) references to it should be marked for garbage collection, right?

on another side note, i tried to run the program on a really massive machine (64GB RAM). the program finished successfully but never released a single byte of memory before it was closed. why? if there are no more references to an object plus if the object goes out of scope, why is the memory never released?

Comment: Isn't the real question here why the strings end up in generation 2? You must somehow hold on to them long enough to miss both gen0 and gen1 cleanups. A side note. You could try to do `GC.Collect(2, GCCollectionMode.Optimized)` to speed up the collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> now i can't explain why this happens and how to prevent it. to my understanding, the very moment a variable goes out of scope and has no more (active) references to it should be marked for garbage collection, right?

No. There's no such thing as being "marked" for garbage collection, and *variables* aren't garbage collected: objects are. And an object which is already in gen2 won't be garbage collected until the next time the GC looks at gen2, which is relatively rare.

> for various reasons i have to process the file line-wise.

Then there's your answer: use [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) if you're using .NET 4, and write the equivalent (it's easy) if you're not. Then you don't need the whole file in memory at a time - just one line. Your memory usage should absolutely plummet. (Note that that's `ReadLines`, *not* `ReadAllLines` - the latter will read the whole file into an array of strings, which isn't what you want.)

> on another side note, i tried to run the program on a really massive machine (64GB RAM). the program finished successfully but never released a single byte of memory before it was closed. why?

If you're talking about memory that the process takes from the operating system, I don't *believe* that the CLR ever releases memory. I assume it takes the approach that if you've used that much memory once, you'll probably use that much again.

Comment: ok i probably typed too fast and didn't re-read what i actually wrote. so, for various other reasons i need the whole text file in memory because i'm also doing a lot of random access on the text file. also, i just wanted an explanation for what i'm seeing. thanks.

Comment: just to elaborate things a bit. the file is generated by a DNA sampling device with a rather cryptic file format. some DNA samples spread more than one line, others don't. the interpretation of values found in one line depend on values found in other lines. and so on. the goal is to transform that huge text file into a collection of custom objects which are analyzed and saved to a DB. it's a bit complicated to explain all that stuff but it is important to see the file as a whole while parsing it. all i need to know is why calling GC.Collect(); seems to solve the issue and what do to about that

Comment: i really want to upvote your comment but my rep is too low :(

Comment: @lightxx: While it's *rarely* a good idea to call `GC.Collect()` yourself, there can be some strange situations where it's useful - and it sounds like this could be one of them.